# Why am I not able to fetch data from my server and getting an empty array on my cart page using react-redux and redux toolkit with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use react-redux and redux toolkit to create cart reducer and action for my cart page. Everything seems to be fine but I'm not sure why I not able to fetch data from my server and I keep getting an empty array from redux devTools extension!!

here is my cartReducers.js code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: { cartItems: [] },
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      const item = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);

      if (existItem) {
        state.cartItems = state.cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
        );
      } else {
        state.cartItems.push(item);
      }
    },
    removeItemFromCart(state, action) {
      const productId = action.payload;
      state.cartItems = state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== productId);
    },
  },
});

export const { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

and here is my cartActions.js code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } from "../reducers/cartReducers";

export const addToCart = (id, quantity) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

  dispatch(
    addItemToCart({
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      quantity,
    })
  );

  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};

export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(removeItemFromCart(id));

  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

here is my store.js code:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  productListReducer,
  productDetailReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducerss";

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetail: productDetailReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
  preloadedState: initialState,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(...middleware),
});

export default store;
```

here is my backend server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const productRoute = require("./routes/product");

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running...");
});

app.use("/api/products", productRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server is running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`
  )
);
```

and here is my Cart.jsx code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Image,
  Form,
  Button,
  Card,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../redux/actions/cartActions";

const Cart = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const quantity = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("quantity") || 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(addToCart(id, quantity));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, quantity]);

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };

  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate("/login?redirect=shipping");
  };

  console.log(cartItems); // Check the value of cartItems
  console.log(cartItems.length); // Check the length of cartItems

  return (
    <Row md={8}>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <Message>
            Your cart is empty <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Control
                      as="select"
                      value={item.quantity}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>
                Subtotal (
                {cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0)}) items
              </h2>
              $
              {cartItems
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn-block"
                disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                onClick={checkoutHandler}
              >
                Proceed To Checkout
              </Button>
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

I have checked my code and the way I dispatched the actions from my reducers, and it all seems to be fine, and still not getting and item to show up in the cart page!

Also, I'm not getting anything stored in the localStorage.

Please, I would strongly appreciate any help :).

Thank you.